# try to derive sin(z) wrt z, where z is a vector

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, analysis, matrix-calculus, machine-learning

I am sitting right now on a exercie matrix calculus and i am little stuck up by the basics because i am not a mathematician rather a comeputer scientist and my question

Is $\sin(z)$ where $z \in {\mathbb R}^{n}$ same as
\begin{bmatrix} \sin(z_1)  \\ \sin(z_2)  \\...\\ \sin(z_n) \end{bmatrix} ?

Comment: You should have been given how it is defined, we cannot guess what definition is intended.

Comment: what you exactly mean ?

Comment: If you are at an exercise requiring you to work with $\sin(z)$ where $z$ is a vector,  then it should have been stated earlier how $\sin(z)$ is defined. The usual definition of $\sin(z)$ is for real or possibly complex values of $z$, so whatever it is for an arbitrary vector should be specifically stated in the text or notes you are reading.

Comment: https://mml-book.github.io/book/mml-book.pdf , exerice 5 , 5.7b) z is a vector from real numbers

Comment: Have you even read the entire exercise? It says “where $\sin(\cdot)$ is applied to every element  of $z$”

Comment: oh sorry i am from germany :( that means my notation above is correct right?

Comment: Yes that is correct. I apologize if I came a cross harsh but for the future you should always share what you know, including the full description of the exercise.

Comment: yeah but sometimes the people here are not answering my question which is based on a small problem, they already give me the whole solution and suddelny they do not answer anymore, because of this i try to give the minimum what is sometimes necceassry :) thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$
\def\a{\alpha}\def\o{{\tt1}}\def\p{\partial}
\def\L{\left}\def\R{\right}
\def\LR#1{\L(#1\R)}
\def\vecc#1{\operatorname{vec}\LR{#1}}
\def\Diag#1{\operatorname{Diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\operatorname{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\m#1{\left[\begin{array}{r}#1\end{array}\right]}
$Let $f(\a)$ denote any function of a scalar variable $(\a)\,$ and $\,f'\!=\grad{f}{\a}\;$ its derivative.

This relationship is best expressed in differential form
$\,(df=f'\,d\a)\;$
because when the function is applied elementwise to a vector argument $(a)$ it is the differential relationship which holds, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
f &= f(a),&\quad g = f'(a) \\
df &= g\odot da \\
}$$
where $\odot$ denotes the elementwise/Hadamard product. But recall that an elementwise product between vectors can be replaced by converting one of the vectors into a diagonal matrix, e.g.
$$\eqalign{
G &= \Diag{g} \qiq Ga = g\odot a \\
}$$
Applying this substitution to the differential allows one to recover the gradient
$$\eqalign{
df &= G\,da \\
\grad{f}{a} &= G \;=\; \Diag{f'(a)} \\
}$$
Remember, the above analysis applies to **any** function. In this particular problem
$$\;f=\sin,\quad f'\!=\cos \\$$